# Set an animaged GIF as a wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background

Converting away from GIF is an option, I just can't seem to find a modern set of instructions that does what I want.

There are a few tutorials out there, but one of them disables desktop functionality (uses xwinwrap, but no desktop icons or folders) and the rest are quite old, I'm not certain they even pertain to modern Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 3):

It is relatively easy to do in KDE - one would need a script in QML language to do it. However, it will be an intended functionality, not a hack. Just go to `/usr/share/kde4/apps/plasma/wallpapers/org.kde.animals` and adapt the script to your needs. 
As per [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-animatedimage.html) the script

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
 width: animation.width; height: animation.height

 AnimatedImage { id: animation; source: "animation.gif" }

}
```

should actually be enough to start with. copy `org.kde.animals` folder to some new name or edit it in place. There are only two relevant files in it. Browse them, it will be easy to understand. Note that you can add reaction to mouse clicks or specific timing.

Comment: Can you give me an example script? I have KDE installed, just trying to figure out what to do.

Comment: Edited. Try now yourself.